# Compare if the elements of two vectors are equal in Julia

Tags: r, vector, julia

I am trying to get the same behavior as `R`'s `==` when applied to two vectors that get the comparison for each element in the vector.

```
a <-  c(1,2 ,3 )
b <-  c(1, 2 ,5 )
a==b
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

I Julia, I came up with a very clumsy way of doing it, but now I wonder if there are easiest ways out there.

```
a = [1 2 3 ]
b = [1 2 5 ]
a == b  #this does not return what I want.
#false  

rows_a =size(a)[2]
equal_terms =ones(rows_a)
for i in  1:rows_a 
        equal_terms[i] =(a[i] == b[i])
end
equal_terms
#1.0
#1.0
#0.0
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Julia you need to vectorize your operation:

```
julia> a .== b
1×3 BitMatrix:
 1  1  0
```

Julia contrary to Python and R will require explicit vectorization each time you need it. Any operator or function call can be vectorized just by adding a dot `.`.

Please note that `a` and `b` are horizontal vectors  and in Julia such are presented as `1×n` matrices. Vectors in Julia are always vertical.

Comment: The [Noteworthy differences from R](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/#Noteworthy-differences-from-R) section of the manual mentions `.` for element-wise operations in the specific contexts of Matrix multiplication and `ismissing` checks. Perhaps it's worth adding as a separate general point, since this seems to be a common stumbling block for newcomers.